# Autowrap text in xlsx

Tags: excel, phpspreadsheet

I want to "autowrap" a long text.
I tried

```
$cell_st =[
 'alignment' =>['wrap' => true]
];
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:A50')->applyFromArray($cell_st);
```

It looks its behaviour doesn't reflect the excel autowrap option

[image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e6PkKvHRgvw/maxresdefault.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks Phpspreadsheet has evolved its syntax a lot during years.
Despite several (old) examples around the web shows `wrap` usage, the current version uses **`wrapText`** to reflect excel "Wrap text".